# add lines to end of file - using for loop - linux script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, awk

I am having file node_avg.in. this file changes value every 5 min accordingly AVAIL_NODE should calculate. kindly help

```
[root@localhost sample]# cat node_avg.in
 QUEUE_NAME | ALLOC_NODES | RUN_NODES  | AVAIL_NODE
 team1      | 2384        | 1019       | xxx
 team2      | 300         | 280        | xxx
 team3      | 90          | 0          | xx
 team4      | 240         | 236        | 
 team5      | 90          | 27         | 
 team6      | 120         | 0          | 
 team7      | 270         | 146        |
```

I just tried, but couldn't helped.pls have a look in below script

```
 [root@localhost sample]# cat avg.in
 for i in team1 team2 team3 team4 team5 team6 team7 
 do
 ALLOC_NODES=$( cat /root/script/sample/node_avg.in | grep $i | grep -v QUEUE_NAME | awk '{print $3}')
 RUN_NODES=$(cat /root/script/sample/node_avg.in | grep $i | grep -v QUEUE_NAME | awk '{print $5}')
 avail=$($ALLOC_NODES - $RUN_NODES)
 done
```

[root@localhost sample]#

Comment: You showed us a file, not clear if it's a sample input file or a desired output file, and a script that does NOT do whatever it is you want to do and asked us to help you do whatever you are trying to do. Think about that. You may want to edit your question to be provide clear sample input, expected output, and requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something much easier, as `awk -F\| '{ print $1  $2-$3}'` to do the calculation for you.

```
cat node_avg.in | awk -F\| '{ print $1  $2-$3}'  | tail -n +2
 team1      1365
 team2      20
 team3      90
 team4      4
 team5      63
 team6      120
 team7      124
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use double `(` `)` to evaluate expressions:

```
avail=$(($ALLOC_NODES - $RUN_NODES))
```